# Workflow engine in Javascript

Tags: javascript, workflow, state-machine

Does anybody know a workflow engine (such as Spring WebFlow) for Javascript? We have a home-made framework that allows us to guide site navigation using JSON, but its quality is far from good.

*Edit based on given answers: the engine must run on the browser and reduce to minimum the number of requests to the server.*

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As suggested by katspaugh I'm posting the libraries I found as the answer.
List of workflow libraries that I've found until now:

- XState - https://github.com/davidkpiano/xstate
- Workflow.js for Backbone.js https://github.com/kendagriff/workflow.js
- Sprout Workflow Engine https://github.com/bstaats/workr
- Javascript Finite State Machine https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine
- State chart https://github.com/DavidDurman/statechart
- machina.js https://github.com/ifandelse/machina.js
- jWorkflow https://github.com/tinyhippos/jWorkflow
- Stately https://github.com/fschaefer/Stately.js

Comment: Which of these frameworks run in the browser and which run on the server? I imagine the ones for Backbone and SproutCore are server-side. FSM, statechart, and machina look like they can run in the browser.

Comment: Stately.js works on both, server and browser side.

Comment: machina.js works both in the browser and in node.

Comment: To save others time, as of June 2016, only Javascript Finite State Machine and machina.js have had commits in 2016, and Stately in 2015.

Comment: To update on the previous comment, as of September. 2020, XState is being actively maintained and from experience it is a very robust and well built library adhering to the [SCXML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/).

Answer (score 7):

### [dataflo.ws](https://github.com/apla/dataflo.ws)

It's a JSON-based workflow engine. It features:

- modular design
- several useful built-in tasks (MongoDB, OAuth, RabbitMQ)
- HTTP initiator with a router

Works on Node.js, in browsers (including IE9) and in PhoneGap.

GPLv3, code on GitHub: https://github.com/apla/dataflo.ws

Comment: Last release on march 2016 no issue tracker activity since 2013. Seems like another JS abandoned project.