# Managing image workflow with Node.js webapp?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, qr-code

I'm new to Node, and was hoping to use Node.js for a a small internal webapp for managing workflow for product photos.

The image files are RAW camera files, and stored on a local NAS device.

The webapp should:

- Have a concept of workflow, and be able to jump back/forth between states, and handle error states.
- Watch certain directories for image files, and react to new files being added, or existing files being moved/removed.
- Send out emails in response to events.
- Scan photos for QR barcodes, and generate events based on these.
- Rename photos based on user-defined batch patterns in response to events.

Questions:

- Is Node.js a suitable tool for something like this? Why or why not?
- Any libraries to help manage the workflow? I could only find node-workflow (http://kusor.github.io/node-workflow/) - curious for anybody's experiences with this? Alternatives?
- Likewise for file watching? I saw many wrappers for fs.watch (e.g. https://github.com/mikeal/watch), as well as some alternatives (e.g. https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) - any advice for somebody new to Node?
- Apart from using a NAS with a network filesystem, are there any other alternatives stores I can use for the image files?

I'm open to other alternatives here. I'm worried that the system will get confused or lose track of files.

The Node.js docs also mention that watching files on network file systems might be unreliable (http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener). Are there more robust solutions?

Any other tips/suggestions for this project?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is a fine platform for building an application like the one you describe. The key question is file storage. You might find this post very interesting:

[Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

This other post enumerates a few interesting options for writing workflows:

[Workflow engine in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414849/workflow-engine-in-javascript/10415153#10415153)

Shameless add: I have been working on an event coordination library that you might find useful and interesting.

http://durablejs.org