# What is a good JavaScript or AngularJS workflow framework for drag/drop, grouping and drill-down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, frameworks, workflow

I have been looking at [several other suggested frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414849/workflow-engine-in-javascript) (and others) to fulfil our needs, but the examples in some seem to be too basic, or don't really show what I'm looking for.

I would like to create a [flow-based programming](http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/fbp/) type client-side editor.

Here is a basic wire-frame I created to assist (Something similar to the soon-to-be discontinued [Yahoo! Pipes](http://Something%20similar%20to%20the%20Yahoo!%20Pipes%20editor,%20but%20with%20different%20features...) editor, but with different features...):

[image: Workflow Editor]

Using the [AngularJS Drag and Drop library](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested) gives me some of the features (containers, items), but I can't see this working the way I'm hoping.

[NoFlowJS](http://noflojs.org/example/) is not what I am looking for, although [this](http://app.flowhub.io/#example/6699161) is pretty cool.

I would like the user to make their selections from the LHS, where if a group like Cats is dragged over to the right, a new "Selected Groups" section would contain all subsequent.  Similarly with Cities, below.  Basically being able to define a grouping type container.

In this case, `Cats` is a grouping of cat types, `Dogs`, the same, etc.

The user can then link the Selected Groups to the Selected Cities - so be able to link grouping containers on the RHS.

This last requirement isn't difficult to implement with regular JS, however, some frameworks I have seen are GL type and may not be as simple to implement:  if double-clicking on any of the individual groups, I would have a modal window pop up with the group's properties, ie. Cats {tabby, calico, etc.} (or do anything else).

The lists on the LHS are scrollable.

The current technology stack is AngularJS, KendoUI .Net MVC5, C#.

I see this as all being client-side until the user wishes to save the current status.

I would appreciate some suggestions - maybe some are a combination of different technologies, but all the same, would like some direction on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found what I was looking for with [ng-sortable](https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable).

Great demo [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCyiu.png).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a side by side select list.  For example, like:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Side-By-Side-Multi-Items-Pick-List.html

Drag and drop won't work on a mobile/tablet device and is tedious to do with a mouse.  :-)