# Mongodb flexible email notification conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose, mean-stack

I am searching for a way to store conditions in mongodb, to be queried and checked, then do something as a result of the condition check.

First off here is an example of the event object that I am considering

```
{
  "name": "My Event",
  "created": 1490726092221,
  "startDate": 1490726092221,
  "endDate": 1490726097810,
  "notifications": [
    {
      "message": "{event.Name} Created", // message template
      "status": 0, // 0=initialized 1=failed 2=sent
      "sendDate": null, // date that the notification was sent
      "sentTo": ["c2a34dfg32c1d4583e73a123"] //members to send notification to
      "criteria": {
        "script": "event.created >= 0 && this.status < 2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "members": [
    {
      "_id": "c2a34dfg32c1d4583e73a123" // Reference to the user
    }
  ]
}
```

The use case, I want to have customizated notifications for an event. So if an event is scheduled it could have notifications for when it is created, when the event start date is within a few days, when a member joins etc. While I could code all of these into javascript functions and correspond to them by an enum for the notification criteria, or have hooks for when certain events happen, this seems like a strict approach.

What I am envisioning is possibly a scripting language that can be stored as a string on the document, which can be queried and evaluated, which will return a boolean to trigger the notification or not.

The script would need to have the event as an input variable, as well as a few special input variables to be available to the script.

This could be done with javascript and `eval()` but that scares me. Are there any other tools that can be used for this use case? Or, are there any suggestions for a better approach to this problem?

Comment: You can store name of the js script in your document, which you can call with parameters (even the documents own fields) upon retrieving the document,

criteria: {
        script: "someScript.js"
      }

like `require("/../notification-scripts/" + doc.criteria.script)()`

Comment: Thats a decent idea. It still requires having hard coded scripts though. my goal is to have a user-created set of notifications. Which is hard to do safely, and I may end up ditching

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are building a workflow engine with a MongoDB back end.  I would start by researching things like the ones listed in this answer [Workflow engine in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414849/workflow-engine-in-javascript)

Comment: Could you give some more insight into how workflow engines would be used in my use case?

Comment: You really need to read about workflow engines and understand them well.  If you had done that, you would not have asked that question.  So what I can do is reiterate, read in detail about workflow engines, so you do not reinvent the wheel without evening knowing wheels exist.  I don't appreciate having my time wasted with another question just because you were not willing to google 'workflow engine'.  So I am downvoting your question.

Comment: You entire comment back was a waste of time. I have researched it and have learned about FSM in-depth in my courses. I have read about workflow engines and I don't understand the connection to my application, so I then asked a follow up question to help guide me some more. I don't doubt your suggestion is applicable, but I just don't understand it after some research. 
Please don't assume what I have done before responding to a comment rudely. I may just still not understand, which is precisely what this site is for. Regardless, thank you for your answer and comments.